# Jackson objectMapper.readValue(File) modifes the original file while reading

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

It seems like the `readValue()` method modifies the file after reading. It happens with Jackson version 2.9.8 and version 2.9.10.3

This is the method I call to serialize the object to file and it serializes perfectly.

```
public void saveToFile() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writerFor(Type.class).withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\File.json"), object);
    }
```

When I deserialize I use this call:

```
public Type restoreFromFile() throws IOException { 
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();        
       Type restoredObj = objectMapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\File.json"), Type.class);
    }
```

When the debugger passes to the next instruction (just a for loop that doesn't touch the file in any way, but iterates on the `restoredObj`) my `File.json` changes as if another `Obj` of class `Type` get serialized without following the same tags that the normal serialization uses (it puts some of the values at `null` and doesn't serialize using `@JsonIdentityInfo`).

Note that the `Obj` gets deserialized correctly the first time I call the `restore()` method, but if I call it twice in a row the `Obj` gets deserialized with `null` values instead of the correct ones.

Comment: It is difficult to help you at the moment. Please  post your code - the method with the for loop in - and it may be easier to help.